# How do I return an array of float3's from my compute shader?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compute-shader

Basically I'm trying to handle ray-tracing on my compute shader and I've tested that it does work and outputs any individual float3 correctly, I made a much slower implementation where individual pixels were rendered on the GPU and copied back to the CPU every time, very slow but it proved my maths in the GPU ray tracing function were sound and gave the right results.

However I'm having difficulty outputting an array of float3's as the RWStructuredBuffer confuses me somewhat

Here is my RWStructuredBuffer

```
RWStructuredBuffer<float3> Data: register(u0);
```

Nothing special but there for reference

Here is my function on the compute shader that I call with Dispatch

```
groupshared uint things;
[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void RenderRay(uint3 Gid : SV_GroupID, uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint3 GTid : SV_GroupThreadID, uint GI : SV_GroupIndex)
{
    float4 empty = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    uint offset = 0;
    float3 pixel;
    float invWidth = 1 / float(width.x), invHeight = 1 / float(height.x);
    float fov = 30, aspectratio = width.x / float(height.x);
    float angle = tan(M_PI * 0.5 * fov / 180.);
    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
    for (uint y = 0; y < height.x; ++y) 
    {
        if(y>0)
        offset += height.x;
        for (uint x = 0; x < width.x; ++x)
        {
            float xx = (2 * ((x + 0.5) * invWidth) - 1) * angle * aspectratio;
            float yy = (1 - 2 * ((y + 0.5) * invHeight)) * angle;
            float4 raydirection = { xx, yy, -1, 0 };
            normalize(raydirection);
            pixel = trace(empty, raydirection, 0);

            Data[0][x] = pixel;

        }
    }
    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
```

Setting Data[0] = pixel worked for the pixel by pixel implementation since I only needed to return the one value, but I can't achieve the same results trying to output the whole image at once as I can't quite figure out how to add these into an array

Writing it out it sounds like a silly problem but nontheless I'm quite stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the syntax "`[numthreads(1,1,1)]`", what is it doing?

Comment: From my understanding it tells the shader to use a 3 dimensional array of threads for processing, so 1x1x1 in this case, you can pass in threads in the dispatch call too